# Order doesn't match in Stellar

Tags: manageofferoperation, offer

I created an asset (MCoin) on Stellar test-net. I made a sell-offer of 200 MCoin in exchange for XLM and then an offer of buying 200 MCoin for XLM.

But ther orders didn't match.

Here is the script I used to make an offer:

```
var MCoin = new StellarSdk.Asset('MCoin', 'GCKRPJXPGNHBPMRCXEX4MDH532BN5RLUJJOMVACA3CB7E2LWSTKTB5U2');
var XLM = StellarSdk.Asset.native();
server.loadAccount(distributor.publicKey)
    .then(function(account){
        var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
                .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer({
                    selling: MCoin ,
                    buying: XLM,
                    amount : '200',
                    price: 2,
                    offerId: 0,
                }))
                .build();
        transaction.sign(distributorKeyPair);
        //console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));

        server.submitTransaction(transaction)
            .then(function(transactionResult){
                //console.log(JSOn.stringify(transactionResult));
                console.log('\n Success!')
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('An error has occured');
                console.log(err);
            })

    })
    .catch(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
```

When I checked the offers from the accounts, I could see `selling` and `buying` was [Object]. The response when I checked for offers is:

```
{ records: 
   [ { _links: [Object],
       id: 221373,
       paging_token: '221373',
       seller: 'GB3K552PTUQB26X4LUNGPO7FN5GZGQAO2PXMKPCJ5A45ZJISANHFOHPR',
       selling: [Object],
       buying: [Object],
       amount: '200.0000000',
       price_r: [Object],
       price: '2.0000000',
       self: [Function],
       offer_maker: [Function] },
     { _links: [Object],
       id: 221566,
       paging_token: '221566',
       seller: 'GB3K552PTUQB26X4LUNGPO7FN5GZGQAO2PXMKPCJ5A45ZJISANHFOHPR',
       selling: [Object],
       buying: [Object],
       amount: '200.0000000',
       price_r: [Object],
       price: '2.0000000',
       self: [Function],
       offer_maker: [Function] } ],
  next: [Function: next],
  prev: [Function: prev] }
```

Can anyone guide on what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a feature with NodeJS. They don't go deep to reveal every detail down an object.

Note the difference at console.log: offerResult.records VS offerResult

---

```
server.offers('accounts', distributor.publicKey).call().then(function (offerResult) {
    console.log( offerResult.records );
})
```

gives

```
> [ { _links: { self: [Object], offer_maker: [Object] },
    id: 234710,
    paging_token: '234710',
    seller: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT',
    selling:
     { asset_type: 'credit_alphanum12',
       asset_code: 'MCoin',
       asset_issuer: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT' },
    buying: { asset_type: 'native' },
    amount: '200.0000000',
    price_r: { n: 2, d: 1 },
    price: '2.0000000',
    self: [Function],
    offer_maker: [Function] },
  { _links: { self: [Object], offer_maker: [Object] },
    id: 235067,
    paging_token: '235067',
    seller: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT',
    selling:
     { asset_type: 'credit_alphanum12',
       asset_code: 'MCoin',
       asset_issuer: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT' },
    buying: { asset_type: 'native' },
    amount: '200.0000000',
    price_r: { n: 2, d: 1 },
    price: '2.0000000',
    self: [Function],
    offer_maker: [Function] } ]
```

---

WHEREAS

```
server.offers('accounts', distributor.publicKey).call().then(function (offerResult) {
    console.log( offerResult );
})
```

gives

```
{ records:
   [ { _links: [Object],
       id: 234710,
       paging_token: '234710',
       seller: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT',
       selling: [Object],
       buying: [Object],
       amount: '200.0000000',
       price_r: [Object],
       price: '2.0000000',
       self: [Function],
       offer_maker: [Function] },
     { _links: [Object],
       id: 235067,
       paging_token: '235067',
       seller: 'GCBCTFOR2GES3JI5SKCYSDP7ZRIB523WQXZ5QC5FWXSK2FEMFMLJULIT',
       selling: [Object],
       buying: [Object],
       amount: '200.0000000',
       price_r: [Object],
       price: '2.0000000',
       self: [Function],
       offer_maker: [Function] } ],
  next: [Function: next],
  prev: [Function: prev] }
```